# Assign self to UITextFieldDelegate works in iOS 8 not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, ios8, uitextfielddelegate

In the past i have done subclassing of UITableView and `UICollectonView` many times, in which i have assigned self to the delegate and datasource, and it worked fine.

Today i tried to make subclass of `UITextField` and in that I am assigning self to its delegate as

```
self.delegate = self
```

where delegate is inherited from `UITextFiled`.
In above case this is hanging the App forever in iOS 7, but works for iOS 8.
Another surprising thing is, when i try to input the text in it from Hardware keyboard then it works fine but it get hanged on typing characters from On-Screen keyboard.

What may be reason of this, Can any one help me to understand?

Comment: I would love to know if you discovered an answer to this, or even a work around.  I am having a similar issue, and I see that no one helped you on this post.  I am hoping you figured it out!  Here is my issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241104/uitextfielddelegate-works-on-ios-8-but-not-ios-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and I figured it out. The simulator will not raise the keyboard by default anymore. If there is a hardware keyboard available and detectable (for example on a MacBook) the simulator will look for input from it and the simulated iPhone keyboard will not raise. This gives the appearance of a problem with the delegate.  All you have to do is in the Simulator's Hardware menu, under Keyboard, unselect the option for "Connect Hardware Keyboard". I hope this helps.